# Component Exception - Can't find variable: direction

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run this app in react but it keeps giving me that error that it cannot find the variable direction. How do I solve this. The Code is below.

**APP.js**

```
    // Importing Libs

    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, View , SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
    import Header from './APP/Components/Header';
    import StartGameScreen from './APP/Screens/StartGameScreen';
    import GameScreen from './APP/Screens/GameScreen';

    export default function App() {

    const [userNumber, setUserNumber] = useState();

    const startGameHandler = (selectedNumber) => {
      setUserNumber(selectedNumber);
    };

    let content = <StartGameScreen onStartGame={startGameHandler} />;

    if (userNumber) {
      content = <GameScreen userChoice={userNumber} />;
    }

      return (
        
        <View style={styles.screen}>
          <Header title="GUESS THE NUMBER" />
          {content}
        </View>
        
      );
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     screen: {
      flex: 1
     },
    });
```

**GameScreen.js**

```
    import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import {View , Text , StyleSheet, Button, Alert} from 'react-native';


const generateRandomBetween = (min, max , exclude) => {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    const rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    if (rndNum === exclude) {
        return generateRandomBetween(min, max, exclude);
    } else {
        return rndNum;
    }
};

const GameScreen = props => {
  const [currentGuess, setCurrentGuess] = useState(generateRandomBetween(1, 99, props.userChoice));

  const currentLow = useRef(1);
  const currentHigh = useRef(99);

  const nextGuessHandler = direction => {
    if ((direction === 'lower' && currentGuess < props.userChoice) || (direction === 'greater' && currentGuess > props.userChoice) ) {
      Alert.alert('Don\'t lie to me', 'You Can\'t Trick Me' [{text: 'I won\'t lie again , SORRY!', style: 'cancel'}]);
    }
    
  }

  if ( direction === 'lower') {
       currentHigh.current = currentGuess;
  } else {
       currentLow.current = currentGuess;
  }
 const nextNumber = generateRandomBetween(currentLow.current, currentHigh.current, currentGuess);
 currentGuess(nextNumber);



  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
    <Text>Opponent Guess</Text>
    <View style={styles.guessNumberContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.guessText}>{currentGuess}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
       <Button title="LOWER" onPress={nextGuessHandler.bind(this, 'lower')} />
       <Button title="HIGHER" onPress={nextGuessHandler.bind(this, 'greater')} />
    </View>
    </View>
  )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  gameScreenContainer: {
    width: 300,
    maxWidth: '80%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2},
    shadowRadius: 4,
    shadowOpacity: 0.26,
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    elevation: 8 ,
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 15,
    marginTop: 30
  },

  guessNumberContainer:{
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "#FFC45D",
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginVertical: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    width: 200
  },

  guessText:{
    color: "#FFC45D",
    fontSize: 22
  },

  screen:{
      flex: 1,
      padding: 10,
      alignItems: 'center'
  },

  buttonContainer:{
    width: 300,
    maxWidth: '80%',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2},
    shadowRadius: 4,
    shadowOpacity: 0.26,
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    elevation: 8 ,
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 15,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 20
  }
});

export default GameScreen;
```

I have no idea how to fix this , dont even know where to start from. I have tried changing the direction name to something else but still gives an error and i made sure React was imported , i have no idea what i am missing.

Comment: On this line `if ( direction === 'lower') {` the `direction` variable doesn't exist. It hasn't been defined yet. Maybe that block of code is supposed to be inside the `nextGuessHandler` function.

Comment: I am a bit of a beginner at this so i have no idea what that means. So does that mean i have to put the  if ( direction === 'lower') ....... in the nextGuessHandler?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you didn't write the code than it's probably best to ask whoever did. But the reason for the error is that `direction` is being referenced before being declared.

Comment: Okay , how do i declare the direction code up there , i was not the one who wrote the code , its from a youtube tutorial but i am just trying my hands on it for practice

Answer (score 0):

Based on the conversation in the comments I assume you want something like this...

```
const nextGuessHandler = direction => {
    if ((direction === 'lower' && currentGuess < props.userChoice) || (direction === 'greater' && currentGuess > props.userChoice) ) {
        Alert.alert('Don\'t lie to me', 'You Can\'t Trick Me' [{text: 'I won\'t lie again , SORRY!', style: 'cancel'}]);
    }

    if ( direction === 'lower') {
        currentHigh.current = currentGuess;
    } else {
        currentLow.current = currentGuess;
    }
}

const nextNumber...
```

Comment: That worked ! I really appreciate it ! that error is gone now but presented a new error that says "currentGuess is not a function (In 'currentGuess(nextNumber') what does that mean what is the solution to this . Would really appreciate it a bunch if you help me out with this one as well

Comment: If you're trying to update the value of `currentGuess` to `nextNumber ` you need to use `setCurrentGuess(nextNumber)`.

Comment: Sorry to bother you this much hahah now it is saying cant find variable setcurrentGuess , how do i declare it

Comment: Check your letter case. It's already defined... `const [currentGuess, setCurrentGuess] = useState(...`

Comment: Thank you so much !! it is working perfectly now